# google app engine launcher won't deploy application: says application does not exist

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, google-app-engine-launch

I can deploy from the command line using this command:

```
appcfg.py --no_cookies --oauth2 --email=myemail --noauth_local_webserver  update .
```

noauth_local_webserver is what is letting me deploy because it gives me an access token at a location I can access

If I deploy from google app engine launcher, it takes me to a sign in page, I accept, and it returns the token to localhost:8080, and my app isn't running off that port. So the response is "no data received" in a webpage located at localhost:8080

I tried fixing the port by using:

dev_appserver.py --port=11080 .

but that just runs the server from that port, and doesn't solve the launcher problem-- the problem that I can't deploy from the launcher.

More history:

I believe I'm running into this problem because I deployed another app engine project from the launcher under a different email

Now, I'm trying to deploy a different app under a different email from the launcher.

How can I fix the deployment issue from launcher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I don't know why, but I just removed the project from launcher, then added it back, and now I can deploy from launcher again.

Comment: great, so please accept this self-answer so the issue will be seen as properly closed from stackoverflow's viewpoint, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just faced the same issue and this post was very useful - thank-you.

Flow to fix for me was:

1) Delete Google App Engine Launcher config and close Google App Engine Launcher

2) Close browser

3) Open Google App Engine Launcher

4) Re-add config

5) Click Deploy

6) Authenticate on the browser (gets stuck in a loop of "authentication flow succeeded)

7) Hit Run in Google App Engine Launcher

It then deployed and deploys again fine now. Had tried a few other variants but the above cleared the blockage.